# I have to convert one line from ruby to Qt C++

Tags: ruby, qt

I need help from some one to convert the following line of code from ruby to qt c++:

KEY = %w(30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00).map{|s| s.hex}.pack('C*')

Comment: Do you know Ruby or Qt C++? Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: i know qt c++ better than ruby. but I dont know how to do this part=> Use Array#pack to turn the array into a binary string of unsigned 8-bit integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QByteArray key = QByteArray::fromHex(QByteArray("30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00").replace(' ', QString()));
```

Quick explanation:

```
QByteArray("30 81 9F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8D 00")
```

creates temporary QByteArray with your key as string

```
.replace(' ', QString())
```

removes all spaces in temporary QByteArray, so it contains only characters 0..F

```
QByteArray::fromHex()
```

converts hex-encoded QByteArray into QByteArray containing unsigned 8-bit integers (i.e. C++ char type). It means that it takes every pair of hex digits from original QByteArray ( for example "41") and converts it to integer ("41" will be converted to 65 = 4*16 + 1) and appends this value into new QByteArray.

If you need key as a "const char *" you can use QByteArray::constData() method, but you have to remember that the pointer returned by this method is valid only as long as original QByteArray is valid (quote from documentation: "as long as the byte array isn't reallocated or destroyed"). So if you need to store the key data, keep it as QByteArray or make a copy of const char * returned by constData().

Comment: The problem with this is that QByteArray::fromHex() returns a temporary QByteArray object. constData() is then called on this temporary object, which is destructed immediately afterwards. data is then most likely pointing to freed memory.

Comment: @oDx: This answer suggests doing quite a bit of extra work compared to the ones from DigitalRoss or Ferruccio below.

Comment: QByteArray has a constructor which takes a char* and a size. There's no need for any string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the Ruby code does:

1. Create an array of strings, `["30", "81", "9F", ... "8D", "00" ]`.
2. Convert each hexadecimal string in the array to an integer: `[48, 129, 159, ... 141, 0]`
3. Use [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206) to turn the array into a single binary string of unsigned 8-bit integers.

Comment: can you pls explain what actually the 3rd step does? I don't have a clue about it! :(

Comment: The number `48` can be represented in binary in many ways; some of the more common ways are called `long` or `signed short` or `int`, etc. As a single unsigned byte, it is `00110000`. [Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary) are a set of steps for understanding decimal-to-binary conversion. In the end, you get a binary stream: `001100001000000110011111...1000110100000000`

Answer (score 2):

If a simple C array will do:

```
unsigned char KEY[22] = { 0x30, 0x81, 0x9F, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x06... };
```

If you need a QByteArray:

```
QByteArray KEY("\x30\x81\x9F\x30\x0D\x06...", 22);
```

Comment: I believe the original author will also need to know how to cast it to QByteArray (nontrivial).

Answer (score 1):

```
char KEY[] = {
  48, 129, 159, 48, 13, 6, 9, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 13, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, 129, 141, 0
};
```

The result is something slightly different, a flat array of byte values. It would certainly be *possible* to make an array of 1-character-string object references, but it would not be likely to be useful.

Comment: can you pls explain what did you mean by **It would certainly be possible to make an array of 1-character-string object references, but it would not be likely to be useful.**

Comment: I believe the original author will also need to know how to cast it to QByteArray (nontrivial).

Comment: It only needs to be a QByteArray if it needs to use capabilities of a QByteArray which are not available in a plain old C array. In that case, QByteArray has a constructor which takes a char* and a size.